# google-play-service_lib missing or error showing

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android and I want to learn some code projects ,so I've tried to import in my adt bundle and it is showing error in library like [this photo](http://postimg.org/image/wobaw7goz/).

Actually,I want to solve this following [photo error](http://postimg.org/image/siizny1h7/) too.

I'm sorry I don't have enough reputation yet to upload images 
I would appreciate if you guide me.

Comment: open your Android SDK Manager and update your Google play service lib from their, you can find the icon of SDK in eclipse on top & when you launch it you will find Google play inside Extras

Comment: @Than Htut try my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are the steps to do that :

Click on [image]  on the top on your `Eclipse`

Make sure that you've installed `Google Play services`, they are on the `Extras` folder.

Now you can import it

File → Import → select Android → Existing Android Code into Workspace and on the `Root Directory` you have to link your `WorkSpace` and add this line

```
/android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services
```

Then you have to import it on your APP as follows :

Right-click your App project → Properties → Select Android in Properties window → Select google-play-services-lib

And you'll be able to use it.
Click OK

Comment: & u got answer from my comment :D

Comment: @SmartphoneDeveloper I was typing it I didn't see your comment.

Comment: :D I was bit lazy u gave it a real graphic look. Happy Coding

Comment: i dun understand this part /android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services   where can i add that line ? i m beginner ,carry me please :)

Comment: @Skizo *Skizo*  help me out of this help sir :(

Comment: check this [tuto](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/integrating-google-play-services-on-android--cms-19828)

Comment: Where it puts RootDirectory you must add your workspace patch plus this lane

Comment: @ThanHtut If I helped to you feel free to upvote and mark this answer as a correct :)